# Error with submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a site http://www.labanda.cl/ and I have a strange error with the submenu or subsections like "servicios".

When I move the cursor on this the rest of subsections this dissapear.

How can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a simple and common mistake - you've applied the CSS "visible" style (for when the menu is visible) to the `<a>` tag. When you hover the `<a>` tag, it shows the submenu, then when you go to click a submenu item, you're not hover the `<a>` any more, so it hides it again.

If you apply the hover selectors the the `<li>` containing the `<a>` tag, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You have a css class:

```css
#nav ul ul {
    position: a
    bsolute;
    display: none;
    width: 14em;
    top: 2.5em;
    ...
}
```

delete `top: 2.5em;`

Comment: @Felipe, I'm glad to help, but please don't forget to accept answers